# Solr copyField order

Tags: search, solr, full-text-search

In Solr does the order of the copyField mentioned in schema.xml makes any difference to search results?
Ex:

```
<copyField source="name" dest="text" /> 
<copyField source="title" dest="text" />
<copyField source="description" dest="text" />
```

What if I have

```
<copyField source="description" dest="text" />
<copyField source="title" dest="text" />
<copyField source="name" dest="text" />
```

Is order of the text stored in '**text**' will it have any effect if we perform fulltext search on 'text' field?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It does not depend on the order to the field definition, unless you have a maximum field length defined in which case the terms would be discarded.
However, the discard terms would also not be controlled by the order defined but rather the order in which the data is fed to Solr or ordered by it internally.
Else, the search should behave in the same manner.